# How perform one final action when user android app completely closes - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

so currently I'm developing an app for Android in Android studio. Basically, when the user presses the home button, tabs button or shuts off the screen (while the app runs in the background ) a string of text gets encrypted, stored and the app logs out. Problem is, it takes a couple seconds for the encryption to go through, so if the user closes the app by going to tabs mode and swiping it away before the encryption is complete the whole process gets cancelled. Is there a way where even though the user shuts off the app it can process the final encryption or a final function?

Comment: if you start a service, which will be independent of your activity's lifecycle, it can continue working even after activity is destroyed.

Comment: Read about `AsyncTask` , i think you can exit yor application `onPostExecute`

Comment: I should mention im a bit new to android studios and would very much appreciate some examples if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to do something like this in your MainActivity( DashboardActivity) of app

```
        private Boolean exit = false;

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

            if (exit) {
                super.onBackPressed();
            } else {
                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() <= 0) {
                    Utilities.showToastCompulsary(DashboardActivity.this, "Press Back again to Exit.");
                    exit = true;
                    encryptionProccess();
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            exit = false;

                        }
                    }, 3 * 1000); //manage your time as per process
                } else {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }
        }
```

one another approch is you can try with onDistroyed method

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    startLoader();
    encriptionProcess();
    stopLoader();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: This answer will not solve the problem as encryption algorithm speed will differ from device to device so you cannot come up with handler.

Comment: update my answer !! may be this help you !! onDestroyed called before activty killed by system so you can say this this is last method call of that activity